# LibreOffice: Open in current program by default?

Tags: libreoffice

I often need to open pipe delimited `.txt` files in LibreOffice Calc. However, once I have Calc running, if I do *File* > *Open* and select a spreadsheet with the extension `.txt`, it opens it in Writer instead.

Is there a way to tell the file I'm trying to open using whatever program instead of trying to pick which one to use?

Barring that, is there a way I tell it to always use Calc for `.txt` files (when I open them from the open dialog in Calc)?  I still want them to open in GEdit like they currently do if I double click them from Thunar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the functionality I need by removing LibreOffice Writer all together.  Now when I open a text file, it pops up a "what kind of file" is this dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Text CSV" in the file type list in the open dialog, and it should open in Calc.

Comment: **by default** is an important part of this question.  I do know how to manually override it.

Comment: Is there a way to tell LibreOffice to do that by default when opening a txt file?